# How does MediaCapture.StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync method work?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Why is Windows documentation so lacking ?? It seems impossible to find an example of how this method is supposed to work [StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700847.aspx)

What I am trying to do is get a preview image from a video source (via [MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) but can't understand how this method works (especially what the second parameter, [IMediaExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.imediaextension.aspx), is supposed to be/do).

Any chance any of you can help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to get a preview frame every now and then, there is a sample on the Microsoft github page that is relevant, although they target Windows 10. You may be interested in migrating your project to get this functionality.

[GetPreviewFrame](http://aka.ms/2015buildgetpreviewframesample): This sample will capture preview frames as opposed to full-blown photos. Once it has a preview frame, it can edit the pixels on it.

Here is the relevant part:

```
private async Task GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync()
{
    // Get information about the preview
    var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

    // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame
    var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);

    // Capture the preview frame
    using (var currentFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
    {
        // Collect the resulting frame
        SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

        // Add a simple green filter effect to the SoftwareBitmap
        EditPixels(previewFrame);
    }
}

private unsafe void EditPixels(SoftwareBitmap bitmap)
{
    // Effect is hard-coded to operate on BGRA8 format only
    if (bitmap.BitmapPixelFormat == BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8)
    {
        // In BGRA8 format, each pixel is defined by 4 bytes
        const int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;

        using (var buffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
        {
            // Get a pointer to the pixel buffer
            byte* data;
            uint capacity;
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out data, out capacity);

            // Get information about the BitmapBuffer
            var desc = buffer.GetPlaneDescription(0);

            // Iterate over all pixels
            for (uint row = 0; row < desc.Height; row++)
            {
                for (uint col = 0; col < desc.Width; col++)
                {
                    // Index of the current pixel in the buffer (defined by the next 4 bytes, BGRA8)
                    var currPixel = desc.StartIndex + desc.Stride * row + BYTES_PER_PIXEL * col;

                    // Read the current pixel information into b,g,r channels (leave out alpha channel)
                    var b = data[currPixel + 0]; // Blue
                    var g = data[currPixel + 1]; // Green
                    var r = data[currPixel + 2]; // Red

                    // Boost the green channel, leave the other two untouched
                    data[currPixel + 0] = b;
                    data[currPixel + 1] = (byte)Math.Min(g + 80, 255);
                    data[currPixel + 2] = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And declare this outside your class:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}
```

And of course, your project will have to allow unsafe code for all of this to work.

Have a closer look at the sample to see how to get all the details. Or, to have a walkthrough, you can watch the [camera session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-730) from a recent //build/ conference, which includes a little bit of a walkthrough through some camera samples.

**Alternatively**, if you're bound to 8.1, you can look into the [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859593.aspx), which can [notify you when there's a new preview frame available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.previewframeavailabledelegate.aspx).

Comment: Wanted to keep the code I already had and not use Lumia Imaging SDK but I ended up using it as I am targeting WP 8.1 as well. Thanks

Comment: This example doesn't even include the `StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync` function. I still am yet to know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are much of examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). If you are developing for Windows Phone 8.1 - samples are [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7)
According [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication/cs) example recording looking like this:

```
private StspMediaSinkProxy mediaSink;
mediaSink = new StspMediaSinkProxy();

MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Qvga);

var mfExtension = await mediaSink.InitializeAsync(encodingProfile.Audio, encodingProfile.Video);
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync(encodingProfile, mfExtension);
```

So, you can understand how to get IMediaExtension from MediaEncodingProfile from this example.
You haven't post any code, but making Preview should be similar to code I have provide